# Does C++11 guarantee a dying object will be moved rather than copied as an argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, move-semantics, language-design

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void f(const vector<int>&) {}
void f(vector<int>&&) {}

int main()
{
    {
        vector<int> coll;

        //
        // coll is dying, so,
        // "f(coll)" will call "f(const vector<int>&)" or
        // "f(vector<int>&&)" as per C++11?
        //
        f(coll); 
    }
}
```

In the code above, `coll` is dying; so, `f(coll)` will call `f(const vector<int>&)` or `f(vector<int>&&)` as per C++11?

Comment: No; in this case it will call `f(const std::vector<int>&)`. In the call that you are making, `coll` is a named lvalue. The fact that `coll` will go out of scope in the next line is irrelevant. If you want to call the rvalue version of `foo`, then you should use `f(std::move(coll))`.

Comment: What do you mean _"`coll`  is dying"_?  It will be destructed after the call. You probabbly meant something like `foo(vector<int>());`

Comment: `coll` is not "dying" (going out of scope) until after the brace `}`. Within the brace, it's perfectly healthy :-) Therefore, if you want to get an rvalue you need an explicit `std::move(coll)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `f(coll)` called `f(vector<int>&&)` instead of `f(const vector<int>&)` that would be a violation of the standard, because it would pick the wrong function overload.

It would also be rather confusing if the resolution of the call was different depending on where the call is located and whether there are any subsequent statements after the call using `coll`.

The special treatment is given to [return values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) only:

> If `expression` is an lvalue expression and the conditions for *copy elision* are met, or would be met, except that expression names a function parameter, then overload resolution to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value is performed twice: first as if expression were an rvalue expression (thus it may select the move constructor or a copy constructor taking reference to const), and if no suitable conversion is available, overload resolution is performed the second time, with lvalue expression (so it may select the copy constructor taking a reference to non-const).

Comment: Just to add to this: there is a very strong rationale for *not* allowing the compiler to call the rvalue version of `foo` in this case (even though `coll` is definitely going out of scope in the next line). That is because if this was permitted, then if someone was to add a statement that used `coll` in the next line, the behaviour of the program would change; which would be confusing to most people.